# Sort array based on asynchronous method

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm using [Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/) to read files in the user device, but I need to sort them by modification date.

The method to read the files returns `Promise<Entry[]>`. To find out the modification date, I need to call `Entry`'s `getMetadata` method which has the following signature:

```
getMetadata(successCallback: MetadataCallback, errorCallback?: ErrorCallback): void;
```

Then in the success callback I have access to the `Metadata` object which has the `modificationDate` property I need for sorting.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: and you tried what so far?

Comment: make all your asyncs, store them somewhere and sort after...

Comment: `Promise.all(asyncCalls.map(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => getMetadata((...args) => resolve(...args))` might be something like this

Comment: or just promisify `getMetadata`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd start by [promisifying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) the `getMetadata` method:

```
function getMetadataPromise(entry) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        entry.getMetadata(resolve, reject);
    });
}
```

Then you can use it in your loop and await all metadata, after which you can sort the array by it:

```
readEntries().then(entries =>
    Promise.all(entries.map(entry =>
        getMetadataPromise(entry).then(metadata => {
            entry.metadata = metadata;
            return entry;
        })
    ))
).then(entries =>
    entries.sort((a, b) => a.metadata.num - b.metadata.num) // or whatever
).then(sortedEntries => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedEntries));
}, console.error);
```

Comment: I had to tweak it a little bit and add some typings but it worked, thank you!